# How can to use package XML in Laravel?

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I've trying to use this package XML to Laravel https://sabre.io/xml/install/
I installed the package by composer

How can call this in controller ? Because I get this error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Sabre\Xml\Writer' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installation of XML package in Laravel:

```sh
composer require sabre/xml
```

Usage of Sabre XML in Laravel:

```php
        $xmlService = new \Sabre\Xml\Service();
        $xmlService->namespaceMap = ['http://example.org' => 'b'];

        $xmlService->write('{http://example.org}book', [
            '{http://example.org}title' => 'Cryptonomicon',
            '{http://example.org}author' => 'Neil Stephenson',
        ]);
```

Comment: I had forgotten the "\"  \Sabre\Xml\Service() .... tks